# Google Map API Client Limit Reached

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

We have been using Google Map API to perform geocoding lookups from the client side and had a limit of 2500 per IP address without an API key. Sometime today this stopped working and we are now getting the following error:

```
You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend 
registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_  For more 
information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please 
see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

It now seems that all clients are receiving the above error message even though they have not hit the limit of 2500. Is there any reason why this would suddenly stop working?

Answer (score 0):

The 2500 limit is for each individual domain that hosts a call to the Google Maps API. That means that if you have 2500 clients, and they each make one request a day, you will max out your usage, and all future clients will see that error message. Or you could have one client make 2500 requests in one day and exceed the limit that would apply to all the other clients.

Take note, the 2500 limit is specified to all Web Services APIs *except* for the Distance Matrix API. This API is restricted based on the number of elements rather than individual requests. Therefore, you can get up to 2500 elements by executing 25 requests with 100 elements per request, 250 requests with 10 elements per request and any other flavor of the like. At the end of the day, 2500 is the magic number.

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

Comment: I don't see anything related to a domain limit on that link. Am I missing something?